# Insert only if row doesn't exist - without unique identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run a insert query only if a specific column isn't registered yet, like the client ID. The problem is that the client id in this case isn't UNIQUE, so I tried this, but isn't working:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows(mysql_queryi($con,"SELECT * FROM `boletos_pagos` WHERE numero_cliente = $t_nosso_numero) LIMIT 1;"))){
    echo "Data already inserted... Skipping...<br>";
} else {
    if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `boletos_pagos` (valor_do_boleto, valor_pago, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, multa, status, data_efetivacao, nome_arquivo, numero_cliente) VALUES ('$t_v_nominal', '$u_v_pago', '$t_dt_vencimento', '$u_dt_ocorencia', '$u_juros_multa', 'Pago', '$u_dt_efetivacao', '$nome', '$t_nosso_numero')")) {
        printf("Error on INSERT: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    } else {
        echo "Sucessful INSERT.<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: So make the `client_id` unique, if that is how the table should be structured.  It is better to have the database enforce such constraints than the application.

Comment: The client_id is being generated by a PHP script, and this number is a random number between 1 and 100k. After this number is generated it is then assigned to be the client_id... If I just set this column to be UNIQUE on PhpMyAdmin it will generate another number if the first assigned number exists?

Comment: By the way, what did you mean by "isn't working"? An error, or something else?

Comment: It's returning always Sucessful INSERT

Comment: avoid `SELECT` check + `INSERT` - it's a race condition. just enforce uniqueness in the DB schema.